# Сделать из массивов 1 массив с объектами

Tags: javascript

Есть первый массив:

```
const arr1 = [
  { id: 1, name: "Группа 1" },
  { id: 3, name: "Группа 2" },
  { id: 2, name: "Группа 3" },
];
```

Есть второй массив:

```
const arr2 = [
  {
    groupId: 1,
    title: "Test Title 1",
  },
  {
    groupId: 2,
    title: "Test Title 2",
  },
  {
    groupId: 2,
    title: "Test Title 2",
  },
  {
    groupId: 3,
    title: "Test Title 3",
  },
];
```

Нужно получить массив с объектами вида:

```
const arr3 = [
  {
    title: "Группа 1",
    docs: [
      {
        groupId: 1,
        title: "Test Title",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "Группа 2",
    docs: [
      {
        groupId: 2,
        title: "Test Title",
      },
      {
        groupId: 2,
        title: "Test Title",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "Группа 3",
    docs: [
      {
        groupId: 3,
        title: "Test Title",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: а в чем, собственно, проблема?

Comment: очевидно в том что топикстартер сам не может этого добиться

Comment: @MaximLensky, так-то и потуг не видно. чему помочь? сделать за него?

Comment: @Yugofx попытки то есть же  - на данный момент он сам не может справится, просит помощи

Comment: const items = props.model &&  props.model.groups.map(item => {
    const obj = props.model.docs.find(o => o.groupId === item.id);
    return {docs: obj, title: item.name};
  });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё довольно просто. Пример решения ниже. Используя `flatMap` сводим к единому массиву два других.

```js
const arr1 = [
  { id: 1, name: "Группа 1" },
  { id: 3, name: "Группа 2" },
  { id: 2, name: "Группа 3" },
];

const arr2 = [
  {
    groupId: 1,
    title: "Test Title 1",
  },
  {
    groupId: 2,
    title: "Test Title 2",
  },
  {
    groupId: 2,
    title: "Test Title 2",
  },
  {
    groupId: 3,
    title: "Test Title 3",
  },
];

const arr3 = arr1.flatMap(item => {
  const tempObj = {
    title: item.name,
    docs: []
  } 
  tempObj.docs = arr2.filter(({groupId}) => groupId === item.id);
  return [tempObj]
})

console.log(arr3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Так сделал. Спасибо всё равно.

```
const items =
    arr1.map((itema) => ({
      title: itema.name,
      docs: arr2.filter((itemb) => itemb.groupId === itema.id),
    }));
```